# LINQ to SQL with JOIN, GROUP BY, HAVING and MAX

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to translate this SQL query into LINQ:

```
SELECT
        T1.FileID,
        MAX(T1.Date) AS MaxDate
FROM    
        T1
        JOIN
        T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code
WHERE
        T2.Category = 'C100'
GROUP BY
        T1.FileID
HAVING
        T1.FileID LIKE 'F01%'
```

I am getting all the dates instead of just the Max of each Date per FileID using this:

```
var query =

    from f in db.T1
    join c in db.T2 on f.Code equals c.Code
    group f by new { f.FileID, f.Date, c.Category } into g
    where g.Key.FileID.StartsWith("F01") && g.Key.Category.Equals("C100")
    select new
    {
        g.Key.FileID,
        MaxDate = g.Max(d=>d.Date)
    }
```

This seems more complicated than needed. How can I fix this?

Comment: why in sql you group only by `FileID` but in linq `f.FileID, f.Date, c.Category`?

Comment: Because I don't know how to use LINQ group by...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does your SQL contain only one column in `GROUP BY` clause and LINQ query has three columns instead?

You should also move `where` statement before `group by` in your LINQ query.

```
var query =
    from f in db.T1
    join c in db.T2 on f.Code = c.Code
    where c.Category = "C100"
    group f by f.FileID into g
    where SqlMethods.Like(g.Key, "F01%")
    select new
    {
        FileID = g.Key,
        MaxDate = g.Max(d => d.Date)
    }
```

Comment: As soon as I changed the group statement, g.FileID does not exist in the select statement. Error: 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,LinqSQL.T1>' does not contain a definition for 'FILEID' and no extensions method...

Comment: @nethy Replace `g.Key.FileID` with `FileID = g.Key` within the `select` part of the query.

Comment: Also, where would I put my HAVING condition: m.FileID.StartsWith("F01")?

Comment: I also tried lumping both conditions in the same "where" line and got the same answer. Should "where" and "having" always be separate or is it okay to have them together?

Comment: It works both ways because you're setting `having` condition on column which is `group by` key. You could not do that if e.g. your `having` condition was `Count(*) > 10`.

Answer (score 2):

modify your linq with this :

while writing linq query you need to remember the order you define the formats

```
var query = ( from f in db.T1
              join c in db.T2 on f.Code = c.Code
              where c.Category = "C100"
              group f by  f.FileID into g
              select new
              {
                   FileID = g.Key,
                   MaxDate = g.Max(d=>d.Date)
              });
```

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek  which is unwanted that no need to be defined. see here g.Key.FileID,

Comment: Well, agree there is a small fix